# Proving identity involving sum

Tags: proof-writing, binomial-coefficients, summation

I'm stuck trying to prove the following identity:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{i=j}^k\frac{(-1)^{i+j}{k+1 \choose i}{i \choose j}(4S-i-k-3)!(4S-2i-1)}{(4S-i-j-1)!} $$ $$=\frac{(-1)^{j+k}(4S-2k-3)!{k+1 \choose j}}{(4S-k-j-2)!}$$ $$\forall\  j=0,1,\ldots,k.$$

From checking individual values it seems true. I've tried rewriting the sum, proof by induction starting at $j=k$ and going downwards, and writing a general version of the way I prove it with small $j$ and $k$ (involving common denominator), all without luck. Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: I've realized that equivalently to the above I could try to show that the same sum with limits from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ (or equivalently from $0$ to $k+1$) is equal to zero; i.e. I could also try to show:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{i\ =-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{i+j}{k+1 \choose i}{i \choose j}(4S-i-k-3)!(4S-2i-1)}{(4S-i-j-1)!} =0$$.

Any takers?

Comment: If I wanted to prove this, I would (1) program both sides of the identity and numerically test it thoroughly, to make sure it is exactly right; (2) try generating functions (a la Wilf's generatingfunctionology, or Graham/Knuth/Patashnik's Concrete Mathematics). You could also look into the WZ-method (a la Zeilberger's A=B).

Comment: I checked on Mathematica and it's true indeed.

Comment: Thank you for comments! I checked it on mathematica before posting. @GregMartin Will look into your suggestions!

Comment: @GregMartin : It finally worked out, using Zeilberger's algorithm from his book that you mentioned (the expressions are not pretty though). Thanks a lot!

Comment: @jorgen: Very nice that you got it to work! Yeah, the expressions don't tend to be pretty, but the fact that there's an algorithm to come up with the proof is pretty cool.